# XSLT: Transforming XML attributes to XHTML classes?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a TEI XML document with content like this:

```
<said who="#Bernard">“I see a ring,” said Bernard, “hanging above
me.  It quivers and hangs in a loop of light.”</said>

<said who="#Susan">“I see a slab of pale yellow,” said Susan,
spreading away until it meets a purple stripe.”</said>
```

And I want to output XHTML like this:

```
<p class="Bernard">“I see a ring,” said Bernard, “hanging above
me.  It quivers and hangs in a loop of light.”</p>

<p class="Susan">“I see a slab of pale yellow,” said Susan,
spreading away until it meets a purple stripe.”</p>
```

What's the best way to map the value of the attribute to the XHTML class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <!-- Match root node -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <!-- Apply child nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match <said> elements... -->
  <xsl:template match="said">
    <!-- ...and transform into <p> -->
    <p>
      <!-- Apply attributes and other child nodes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match @who attributes... -->
  <xsl:template match="@who">
    <!-- ...and transform into @class attributes -->
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <!-- Omit the hash mark -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<waves>
  <said who="#Bernard">“I see a ring,” said Bernard, “hanging above
  me.  It quivers and hangs in a loop of light.”</said>

  <said who="#Susan">“I see a slab of pale yellow,” said Susan,
  spreading away until it meets a purple stripe.”</said>
</waves>
```

#### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
  <p class="Bernard">“I see a ring,” said Bernard, “hanging above
  me.  It quivers and hangs in a loop of light.”</p>

  <p class="Susan">“I see a slab of pale yellow,” said Susan,
  spreading away until it meets a purple stripe.”</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Awesome. What does `| node()` do?

Comment: `@*` means all attributes, `node()` matches other nodes, e.g. element and text nodes (see e.g. [Identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT)). The pipe character `|` is a [union operator](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-introxpath1/section6.html) that's used to combine XPath selections.